# Como fazer este sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Eu tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: tabela]

Eu utilizo um comando `SELECT`, tipo:

```
SELECT estudante, conceito_1, conceito_2 FROM estudante WHERE etapa = '1ª'
```

Como eu poderia fazer um único select para pegar a 2ªs e 3ªs etapas também?

E gostaria que o SQL gerasse:

[image: tabela]

Comment: O objetivo da consulta é mostrar tudo menos a etapa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imaginando que sua tabela chama-se `Estudante`, isto pode ser realizado com alguns subqueries:

```
select e.estudante, 
  a11.conceito_1, a11.conceito_2, a11.etapa,
  a22.conceito_1, a22.conceito_2, a22.etapa,
  a33.conceito_1, a33.conceito_2, a33.etapa
FROM Estudante e
JOIN 
  (
        SELECT estudante, conceito_1, conceito_2, etapa
        FROM Estudante where etapa = '1a'
    ) AS a11
ON e.estudante = a11.estudante
JOIN 
  (
        SELECT estudante, conceito_1, conceito_2, etapa
        FROM Estudante where etapa = '2a'
    ) AS a22
ON e.estudante = a22.estudante
JOIN 
  (
        SELECT estudante, conceito_1, conceito_2, etapa
        FROM Estudante where etapa = '3a'
    ) AS a33
ON e.estudante = a33.estudante
GROUP BY e.estudante
```

Você pode ver funcionando aqui neste link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8e0e/1

Não consegui pensar ainda em uma consulta que funcione independente do número de etapas, sem necessidade de adicionar uma nova subquery manualmente.

Comment: Na hora de digitar eu me esqueci do FROM tabela. O problema que eu quero pegar o conceitos de todos os estudantes e depois manipulá-los. Ex.: Maria, conceito_1 (1ª etapa), conceito_1 (2ª etapa), conceito_2 (1ª etapa), conceito_2 (2ª etapa), assim por diante. Como eu poderia pegar todos os estudantes e conceitos e manipulá-los?

Comment: @LuisSouza, infelizmente não consegui entender... edite a sua pergunta ilustrando melhor o que gostaria de ter como resultado.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta. Eu penso que agora dá para entender melhor.

Comment: Ops, está funcionando mais ou menos, vou corrigir.

Comment: Agora está correto.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!

Comment: @LuisSouza , legal! :D Poderia marcar a minha resposta como a solução? Veja como fazendo um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)! Obrigado!